# Spark (using pyspark) use value in one dataframe (structured streaming) to query static dataframe and merge row from second df with first one

Tags: python, merge, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a structured streaming dataframe that I want to, for each row, take the value in one column (in this case a timestamp like 1525670700) and use that value to query another static dataframe for the nearest timestamp to that value and merge the one row returned from that query to the structured streaming data frame e.g.,

`my_row_to_merge_df = weather_df.filter(weather_df.timestamp_unix > 1525670700).sort(col('timestamp_unix').asc()).limit(1).show()`

With that I want to do something like:

`joined_df = streaming_df.merge(function_to_return_row_from_other_df(col('timestamp')))`

The problem with using a join in this case is that the timestamps might not match perfectly, but it is okay if they are a few seconds or even a few minutes different.

So at that, I am not sure what kind of operation I could do to get this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can round a timestamp to the significance level you need with:

```
# Assuming timestamp is in seconds
timestamp_rounded = int(timestamp - (timestamp % int(minutes * 60)))
```

Where "minutes" is the level you want to round to. For example, if you choose minutes = 5 you will round (down) the timestamp to every 5 minutes.

You can add the new column like shown here:[How to do mathematical operation with two column in dataframe using pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728017/how-to-do-mathematical-operation-with-two-column-in-dataframe-using-pyspark)

Comment: Thanks, I had not considered the rounding step, but I think what I was probably unclear about is that what I really want to add is all of the columns returned from the static data frame query, so the timestamp is just used to retrieve the correct columns, but then I want to merge those with the matching row in the streaming dataframe

Comment: Once you have rounded the step can't you just join?

Comment: Now that I've tried it I can add new columns with the rounded time and reference the original time dowstream for analysis. So yes this seems like it's  the most straight forward approach